# when defining a private structure in a class how do i use it as a function parameter or return type?

Tags: c++, graph, structure, copy-constructor, forward-declaration

I have created a graph.h, graph.cpp, and main.cpp
In my graphics.h I've created two private structures an Edge
and a Node, and I've declared Edge first above Node but an 
Edge has a node member so I've forward declared the Node struct
but I'm running into issues saying a "Graph::Node*" is incompatible
with "Node *" this occurs in my graph.cpp AddEdgeByName(string,string,double)
function, why does this happen? On top of this I dont know why I had to declare in (graphics.cpp) the function Graph::Node * Graph::findByName(string name) like that I thought the way i originally tried to declare it like this
Node * Graph::findByName(string name) would work but it gave me an error.
Im trying to make a Directed weighted graph by the way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>



using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

struct Node;

class Graph{

    private:
        typedef struct edge{
            double edgeWeight;
            Node *pointsTo;

            edge(){}
            edge(const edge & copyObject){
                this->edgeWeight = copyObject.edgeWeight;
                this->pointsTo = copyObject.pointsTo;
            }

        } Edge;

        typedef struct node{
            string name;
            vector<Edge> myEdges;// list of outgoing edges for this node

            node(string myName){
                name = myName;
            }

            node(const node & copyObject){
                this->name = copyObject.name;
                this->myEdges = copyObject.myEdges;
            }
            // adds another edge to this node
            void addEdge(Node *pointTo, double weight){
                Edge newEdge;
                newEdge.edgeWeight = weight;
                newEdge.pointsTo = 
                newEdge.pointsTo = pointTo;
                myEdges.push_back(newEdge);
            }
        } Node;

        vector<Node*> graph; // vector containing all the nodes for the
                             //graph
    public:
        Graph();
        // finds a node in the list of nodes for the graph, using the name
        Node * findByName(string name);

        void add(string name);

        void addEdgeByName(string first, string second,double weight);


};

#endif




// this is graphics.cpp

#include "Graph.h"


Graph::Graph(){



}

Graph::Node * Graph::findByName(string name){



    for(std::vector<Node*>::iterator it = graph.begin(); it != graph.end(); ++it){

        if((*it)->name == name){
            return *it;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void Graph::add(string name){

    Node * newNode = new Node(name); // creates a new node with the given                 //name
    graph.push_back(newNode); // adds this node to our list of nodes in the //graph
}

// this publicly accessible function adds edges to each of the strings

void Graph::addEdgeByName(string first, string second,double weight){

    Node * firstNode = findByName(first);
    Node * secondNode = findByName(second);
    firstNode->addEdge(secondNode,weight);
    secondNode->addEdge(firstNode,weight);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `typedef struct node { … } Node` in C++. That's C.

`Node` is a structure inside `Graph` so you need to forward-declare it there, not outside it:

```
class Graph {
private:
    struct Node;

    struct Edge {
        …
    };

    struct Node {
        …
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the public/private problem: You can't. Having the structure with `private` visibility means it is only usable within your code's functions.

Making it `public` would be one solution.  Another option would be to not use nested classes at all. (Personally I don't like them).

---

You should avoid doing `typedef struct edge {....} Edge;`  . Instead use `struct Edge { .... };`  . It gains nothing to give your struct two names.

Your forward declaration `struct Node;` declares a different struct to `Graph::Node`.  Perhaps you meant for `struct Node;` to be inside the `Graph` definition. Then it would be a forward declaration of `Graph::Node`.

Finally, `Graph::` is required in `Graph::Node * Graph::findByName(string name)` because the compiler reads from left to right, so if it sees `Node *` then it doesn't know what you are talking about yet. This problem can be avoided by using C++11 return type syntax:

```
auto Graph::findByName(string name) -> Node *
```

where the names in the `->` part are looked up in the `Graph` scope, since the compiler has already seen that we are implementing a `Graph` member function.